# Network Splitter to Share Wifi Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a network splitter in a room. How can I enable it to share its connection as wifi? Alternatively, if thats not possible. What is a simple item I can buy to share wifi from a desktop computer?

Thanks.

Comment: "Network splitter" is too vague a term. Is it a passive RJ-45 (8P8C) splitter? Then it won't work for Ethernet at all.

Comment: Sorry, its a TP Link TL-SG105 https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-42_TL-SG105.html

Comment: As the page you linked says, that's a 5-port Gigabit Ethernet switch. It doesn't have any Wi-Fi capabilities built-in. You'll still need an AP ("wireless router"), or you'll need to make your desktop PC act as an AP. You can get a decent TP-Link 2x2 802.11ac wireless router from Amazon for US$39. If you want to do modern Wi-Fi on a budget, that would be a good way to go. Making a desktop PC act as your AP is a pain, because you have to keep the PC on and awake all the time, and PCs don't make great APs without a lot of tweaking.

Comment: Thank you Spiff, so something like this connects directly from the switch via ethernet? I'll get that then

Comment: Yes, any wireless router that doesn't have a built-in modem for DSL or DOCSIS will have a WAN Ethernet port. Plug the router's WAN port into the switch or the wall, and do the quick setup of the router so your network has a useful name and a strong WPA2 passphrase, and you're all set. Be sure to get something in the "AC1200" class or better, like this: https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-AC1200-Smart-WiFi-Router/dp/B01IUDUJE0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Ethernet drop in your room, you can connect an 802.11 Access Point ("wireless router" in layman's terms) to it to make so that Wi-Fi client devices can access whatever network that Ethernet cable connects to.

If you have a desktop computer that already has a connection to the network you care about, and you want the desktop computer to host a Wi-Fi network so that Wi-Fi clients can get access to the network via the desktop computer, then you need a spare Wi-Fi interface (could be a PCIe card, could be a USB dongle) for the desktop PC, and it needs to be capable of AP mode (some products/OSes may call this something like "hosted network" mode).